# insert pandas dataframe into mongodb with mongoengine

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, mongoengine

I have some dataframe df, example below
How do I insert the df using mongoengine?

```
illustration:           date    contents
            0   2022-04-20      lorem ipsum
            1   2023-04-20      lorem ipsum
```

I know in pymongo there's insert_many and in mongoengine I can aldo do df.values.tolist() -> 2d list.

and then initialise a mongoengine object with

```
for nested_list in df_list:
    d = mongoenginedocument()
    d.date = nested_list[0]
    d.contents = nested_list[1]
```

Is there a way to do it directly in mongoengine without the list conversion?
My workaround works okay but I'm curious

---

EDIT: the actual mongoengine model has some more fields but is very basic. lets use this as an example

```
import mongoengine
class Doc(mongoengine.Document):

    date = mongoengine.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    contents = mongoengine.StringField(default = "")
    meta = {
        'db_alias': 'core',
        'collection': 'some_collection'
         }
```

Comment: can you show us how your mongoengine model is structured? what fields are defined?

Comment: hi tobin, didnt see this, I edited the post